# Windows 10 PC's Not Showing Others on LAN

Tags: windows-10, networking, lan, file-sharing

Recently I have had issues with my Win 10 pc's not seeing each other in Network. Sometimes, you can type the IP address in manually and it will find the other PC even though it doesn't show in Network. I have read quite a bit online about turning services DNS Client, uPnP Client, and Function Discovery Resource. It seemed to somewhat help, but yesterday it completely quit working again. Thanks

Comment: I have seen this before, and I can only remark that Windows 11 Pro seems to work better for browsing other computers.

Comment: I too have seen this before (like @John).. I ended up doing static IPs and assigning machine names through the hosts file.  I know this doesn't solve your problem. :(